# iframe twitter button css overflow hidden

Tags: css, twitter

I need to use the iframe version of the tweet button in a React component (not to mess with React rendering workflow), but **on Linux/Windows - with Chrome / Firefox, the scrollbars appear** (even with `overflow: hidden`)

```
<iframe title="Twitter Tweet Button" style="border:0;overflow:hidden;" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?count=none&amp;dnt=false&amp;lang=en&amp;size=l&amp;text=%23iframe%20Twitter%20button%20%23css%20problem%20%23overflow&amp;type=share&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fcodepen.io%2Ftopheman%2Fpen%2FwKyGPd&amp;via=topheman" data-reactid=".0.2.0.4" height="28px" width="76px"></iframe>
```

The rendering works fine on:

MacOS X - Chrome / Firefox / Safari
Windows - Firefox

Any hints about that ?

- Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/topheman/pen/wKyGPd)
- Here is the [React code on github](https://github.com/topheman/react-es6/blob/master/src/components/common/TwitterButton.jsx) if you need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the attribute:

```
scrolling="no"
```

in your iframe tag

Comment: Thanks @izorgor it's working fine https://github.com/topheman/react-es6/commit/284a69ee3d09649e5ed21c11e5e3ea86c018a23c